# How to add items to array in a function using pointers?

Tags: c

I am trying to write this function that takes an array input and assigns random numbers between 1-52 to the array. Then prints back the numbers. I get an error message on the 4th line that says expression is not assignable. Is my use of pointers incorrect or is it not possible to add content to array with pointers?

```
void shuffleDeck(int *deck[]) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=52;i++)
       rand()%53 = deck[i]; // I get an error message on this line 
}
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int deck[2000];

    shuffleDeck(deck);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=52;i++){
        printf("%d", deck[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you learning C? Your assignment is the wrong way round.

Comment: `rand()%53 = deck[i]` doesn't make sense, but `deck[i] = rand()%53` does

Comment: 1) `int *deck[]` --> `int deck[]` 2) `rand()%53 = deck[i];` --> `deck[i] = rand()%53;`

Comment: Also, note that `%53` will return numbers in the range `0 to 52` not `1 to 52`. Better to work `%52` and add 1 -- or just use 0 to 51. Along the same lines, you seem to be trying to add 53 cards to the deck rather than 52. Finally, declaring it to have room for 2000 cards is pointless.

Comment: This `int *deck[]` should be `int *deck`. Also take your compiler's *warnings* serious.

Answer (score 2):

Assigment direction is from right to left

So in this expression

```
deck[i] = rand()%52 + 1;
```

- First is called function `rand()`
- Then the result of function `%52`
- Then `1` is added
- And finnally its assigned to `deck[i]`

---

**Array** (what you have in main) is

```
  0   1   2   3   4
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^-------------------------- arr[0]
```

While **Array of pointers** (what your function expects) is

```
      0   1   2   3   4
    +---+---+---+---+---+
    | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |    0
    +---+---+---+---+---+
------^
|   +---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |    1
|   +---+---+---+---+---+
|   +---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |    2
|   +---+---+---+---+---+
|
----------------------------- arr[0][0]
```

When array is passed to function, then `arr[]` and `*arr` are the same. But only as function arguments!

---

3. `%53` returns `0-52`,so if you need `1-52`, use `%52 + 1` (`0-51` + `1` = `1-52`)

---

If you cant solve it, here is code with fixed bugs.

```
void shuffleDeck(int deck[]) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=52;i++)
       deck[i] = rand()%52 + 1;
}
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int deck[2000];

    shuffleDeck(deck);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=52;i++){
        printf("%d", deck[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Some* bugs are fixed (enough for a +1), but it still doesn't make a lot of sense. For one thing, if the numbers 1-52 are supposed to be the 52 cards in the deck, then OP needs a *permutation* of these numbers, something which the code doesn't give. Instead, some cards will be repeated multiple times and other cards will be missing.

Comment: @JohnColeman Which bugs? Which permutation ? OP didnt even mention any permutation or cards. Q is _How to add items to array in a function using pointers?_ and why he gets an error.

Comment: For one thing, I think that `<=52` rather than `<52` is a bug. For another thing -- the names `deck` and `shuffleDeck` suggest cards and an intended application, one for which the code doesn't make sense. To shuffle a deck is to *permute* it. I think that OP needs to do something like initialize an array with the numbers 1-52 and then do something like a fisher-yates shuffle on it. It isn't your fault that OP's code has multiple issues.

Comment: Sure, it suggest that its app for cards and it should be `<52`, but still we arent mind-readers and OP didnt actually asked for that, so why would one creates algorihms for OP? Iam just explaining & fixing _syntax_ errors which is that Q about :-)

Comment: @johnColeman you're right a permutation would be a better way to realistically simulate a card deck. I'm just in the process of learning C (my first language) right now, so I'm starting projects and learning on the go. Thank you for the help everyone.